# converting arrays of primitive double values to references to objects

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to convert arrays of primitive double values to objects. As a result I am getting a "type mismatch error"

```
private double[]purchases;
```

to

```
private CreditCard[]purchases;
```

then when I try to add a value to the array

```
public void purchase(double amount)throws Exception
{
    if (numPurchases<purchases.length)
        if (amount >0 )
            if(amount+balance<=creditLimit)
                if( GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()<=expDate.getTimeInMillis())
                    {
                     balance+=amount;

                     purchases[numPurchases]= amount;
                     numPurchases++;

                  }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("card expired");
                }
            else{
                throw new Exception("insufficient credit");
                }
        else{
            throw new Exception("invalid amount");

        }
    else{
        throw new Exception("exceeded number of allowed purchases");
    }


}
```

the error message says type mismatch for *amount* "cannot convert from double to CreditCard
how can I correct the code to allow me to add purchase amounts to the array?

Comment: @Neil - I wish I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general point here is that you've defined `purchases` so that it must only contain `CreditCard` instances:

```
private CreditCard[] purchases;
```

The type you specify here controls what you're allowed to place in it later. You then attempt to place a `double` into the array:

```
purchases[numPurchases] = amount;
```

But you just told the compiler that `purchases` is only allowed to contain `CreditCard`s!

You need to wrap your `double` in a `CreditCard` instance first.

Imagine you have the following class:

```
public class CreditCard {
    private double amount;
    public CreditCard(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
purchases[numPurchases] = new CreditCard(amount);
```

...because the thing you're putting into the array has the correct *type*.

On a side note, consider renaming your class to `CreditCardPurchase`, if that's what it really represents. The name of your class should say something about what it *is*. If it's going into a `purchases` array, then it's probably a purchase, not the credit card itself.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a CreditCard instance and add that to your array

```
  CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
  creditCard.setAmount(amount);
  purchases[numPurchases]= creditCard;
```